# How to perform addition of 2 numbers with asp.net using web api and Javascript without using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I know there are multiple tutorials for addition of 2 numbers, but my question is how to do addition of 2 numbers, where the system displays the addition of 2 numbers on entering the values in the input box.
eg: value1: 5
value2: 10
result:

the system should display result as 15 as i enter value2 input box.

How is it possible to do using web api with C# ? and without using jquery.

Comment: You want to call web API while you are typing in input boxes? And you don't have a submit button? And you don't want to use jQuery? May be you can use pain JavaScript. Yes it is possible

Comment: Yes there is no submit button, no jquery.                                                                                 but how to call web api using plain javascript. I can put onchange event at the input box but how to render the values from webapi to calculate totals. Can you give me an example please

Comment: I suggest you read and learn about calling API from JavaScript. There are plenty of examples available on internet if you search on Google. https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/ try writing some code using the learnings and ask a question here if you face any issues in the code.

Comment: The document provided is clear to understand how calling API from Javascript, but I am stuck when I am working using C#.

Comment: I have written a code which has asp.net project created: It has api controller where I have method with addition and having [HttpPost] as action, another controller with 
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            
            return View();

        }    
and Index.cshtml which has input type text for value 1 and value 2 . 

So the question is how to perform the operation using javascript and webAPI controller which performs addition without using submit button.

Comment: I have Index.cshtml, with the textbox value 1 and value 2. Controller class with a method having post request [HttpPost]. Since I have a submit button on click of it gives me result.

But I need to get the result in the same page without submit button and without JQuery(auto calculating the values and displaying result as we enter the input values)

Anyone who can help me on this ?

Comment: You need to send request to controller action using JavaScript and display the returned value from controller action. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-AJAX-Call-using-XML-using-XmlHttpRequest-XHR-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx#:~:text=The%20Controller%20consists%20of%20two%20Action%20methods.&text=Inside%20this%20Action%20method%2C%20simply%20the%20View%20is%20returned.&text=This%20Action%20method%20handles%20the,type%20is%20set%20to%20JsonResult.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya   ,  I have a question below is my controller

public ActionResult NetWorth(decimal chequing, decimal savTax, decimal raiDayFund, decimal savFun, decimal savTravel, decimal saveDevel, decimal inv1, decimal inv2, decimal inv3)
        {

            decimal totalAssets = chequing + savTax + raiDayFund + savFun + savTravel + saveDevel + inv1 + inv2 + inv3;

            return Content("Results::"+ totalAssets) ;
           // return View();
    }  how can I return the result in the javascript end in decimal format ?

Comment: Could you please help me on that?

Comment: Can you share the code in the question itself and explain what's the issue you are facing? Did you write any Javascript code? Please share that too..

Comment: I tried using the XMLHttpRequest and returned the value from controller action. And now its working. Thanks @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Cool.. do you want to post your solution as an answer here ? So that other people can benefit from it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya    -- I have posted my answer below. Have a question on this Can I make the data live inside the memory or file or database ? If Yes then how can I do in this scenario.

Comment: I suggest to have more details in the answer. Also ask a different question if you have different problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Sure ..

```
function propertyChange(ev) {            
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //New browsers.
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var formData = new FormData(document.forms.Property);
    }
    if (request != null) {
        var url = "Calculator/NetWorth";
        request.open("POST", url, false);
        request.send(formData)
        
    }

    totalAssets.value = request.response;
}
html code below

<form name="Property"  >
  <p>
      <br/><br />
  </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h2>Property</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Property1  </td>
            <td> 
                <input type="number" onchange="propertyChange(event)"
                       id="property1" name="property1" min="0"
                       value="1500.00"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Property2  </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="property2" name="property2"
                       min="0" value="4100.00" 
                       onchange="propertyChange(event)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Total Expenditure </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="totalExpenditure"
                        name="totalExpenditure" contenteditable="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```